# Last week was the first time/last week it was the first time

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between:

> 1 Last week was the first time I saw an elephant.
>
> 2 Last week, **it** was the first time I saw an elephant.

Comment: The most used way to say this would be: I saw an elephant for the first time last week. Your 1) is OK but 2) is no.

Comment: Both seem more or less OK to me (2 is a bit unnatural on its own but fine as the start of a story), but the grammar is a bit different. The first is describing last week, the second is saying something that happened last week. But do you mean difference in grammar, in meaning, or in something else?

Comment: I mean whether they mean the same and are they both correct?